# how to import class using sparkr

Tags: r, import, sparkr

I have a class with different functions.I want to import the class and use its functions in another different class.I got this implemented in RStudio like "student::show()" where student is a class and show() is function in that class.It is working fine in RStudio but in SparkR,it is throwing error like "Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘student’ ".It will be great if anyone can help with some examples.I have added the codes which I used.

student.R

```
setClass("student",
         slots=list(name="character", age="numeric", GPA="numeric")
)
setMethod("show",
          "student",
          function(object) {
            cat(object@name, "\n")
            cat(object@age, "years old\n")
            cat("GPA:", object@GPA, "\n")
          }
)
```

main.R

```
student::show()
s <- new("student",name="John", age=21, GPA=3.5)
show(s)
```

Comment: please add a brief code example of what you're trying to do. Also, what you are calling `class` is called `package` in R, which is more of a `library` equivalent.

Comment: I have added the code.Kindly look into it

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for an R equivalent of `import your.package.goes.here.student` in Java/Scala, right?

1. it's important to realise that in R, methods are associated with the
   generic function, not the class; so in your example, you've added a
   method for generic function `show` which tells it how to deal with
   an object of class `student`. This is i think different from OO
   languages like java.
2. `student::show` looks for function `show` in *package*, not *class*, `student`. Hence the complaint `there is no package called ‘student’`.

If you want to have your `student` class available when working with `SparkR`, either wrap it in a package and `library` that, `source("path/to/student.R")` in your `Main.R` script, or rethink what you are trying to do: can your `student` be a row in a `data.frame` that has variables `name`, `age`, and `GPA` for your purpose?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.I guess source() would help.But I have the file in hdfs and I guess it is not possible to take the file to source().So,I thought I could download the file from hdfs to local and then do the sourcing.But I'm doubtful whether I will be able to download the file